# Controllers and Helpers

Tags: sorbet

I have a Padrino application with a controller and a corresponding helper (similar to Rails). Sorbet is reporting a method defined in the helper as being missing in the controller which is calling it. Is there anything to do about this in the current implementation of Sorbet?

Answer (score 0):

You can define in an rbi file that the controller includes the helper. That will trick Sorbet to include the methods from the helper

```
# — foo_controller.rbi
class FooController
  include BarHelper
end
```